# How to make a div fixed when using justify-content space between

Tags: css, sass

I am trying to add two divs(left-item-container, right-item-container) to the top of my page and make the left-item-container fixed . I wish to have the left item fixed when the page is scrolled . The right item should be scrolled and can be hidden.

I would also like to have space between the divs.

```
.mydiv{
display:flex
justify-content: space-between;

.left-item-container{
position: fixed;
}
.right-item-container{
}
}
```

When I exclude position fixed the space between works fine - however I loose the fixed position.

I need help to make the left item fixed and also have space between when both divs are visible.

Comment: what HTML you have?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work by giving the container a specific height as well as applying a justify-content of flex-start to the left-container as that is where we'd like it to stay fixed.

```
.mydiv{
display:flex;
justify-content: space-between;

.left-item-container{
border: 10px solid red;
justify-content:flex-start;
position:fixed;
height:30px;
}
.right-item-container{
  border:10px solid blue;
  height:20px;
}
}
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uu8h4n0u/1/)